# how to use Django widthratio tag dynamically?

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I want to calculate percentage of amount. Amount and percentage is stored in models. for eg 25% of 1500, both these value are stored in models.

I tried django `widthratio` tag, but its only taking `{% widthratio  25 100 1500  %}`. its gives me bug when i try `{% widthratio  {{ obj.percent }} 100 {{ obj.price }}  %}`

I tried jquery also, but its working as expected.

```
<p class="course-price" >{% widthratio  {{ obj.percent }} 100 {{ obj.price }}  %}</p>
```

I need to get percentage dynamically(based on the object), i'm loading around 10 objects dynamically(in one page).

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the variable names without the `{{ }}` tags.

Example:

```
{% widthratio obj.percent 100 obj.price %}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but got one issue, widthratio final argument must be a number. can't give obj.price as final argument.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I am starting to think `widthratio` is not even the tool you are looking for

Comment: i have obj.price which is price of item, obj.percent which is percent. i want to show exact price as well as discounted price.Each item as different percent values. according to that percentage has to calculated.